# Save data from combo box in database Javafx

Tags: javafx, combobox

I get an error from this code line:

```
prov = obtenerProveedor(productos_comboPROVEEDOR.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
```

the method obtenerProveedor() is this:

```
public long obtenerProveedor(String s){
    ConexionMySQL conexion = new ConexionMySQL();
    Connection conn = conexion.conectar();
    String query ="select id from proveedores where nombre = '"+s+"'";
    Statement Squery;
    try{
        Squery = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = Squery.executeQuery(query);
        res.next();
        return res.getLong("id");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo obtener el proveedor");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following error:
[This one is the error but I can't put images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLWq8.png)

I'm not sure but I think that the problem is beause the method obtenerProveedor() asks for a String and I send it an object, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Comment out String query and add one below that. The new one should be a full hardcoded String "select .... = ...". If that works, remove the ' symbols from the original String query. I would suggest you learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: No, it's the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
prov = Long.toString(obtenerProveedor(productos_comboPROVEEDOR.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
```